# Grouping records and starting Row Number as a odd number when partition changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table Test (RevObjId int, LegalPartyId int, IsPrimary int)

insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (10, 20, 0)
insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (10, 21, 0)
insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (10, 22, 1)
insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (11, 20, 1)
insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (11, 21, 0)
insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (12, 30, 1)
insert into Test (RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary) values (13, 40, 0)
```

I am looking for the output below:

```
RevObjId LegalPartyId IsPrimary RowNumber
10 22 1 1
10 20 0 2
10 21 0 3
11 20 1 5
11 21 0 6
12 30 1 7
13 40 0 9
```

When I use the following query:

```
select RevObjId, 
       LegalPartyId, 
       IsPrimary, 
       row_number() over(partition by RevObjId order by RevObjId asc,IsPrimary desc,LegalPartyId asc) as RowNumber 
       from test;
```

I get the row numbers in sequence, each row incrememted by one, the row numbers get reset after the partition changes. How can I change the Row Number to the next odd number when partition(by RevObjId) changes?
Here's my SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01d5c/22

We need the gaps between the row numbers because I need to generate the report in the following format.
[image]

Here's a supporting question that I had asked:
[How to convert every other row to column in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916569/how-to-convert-every-other-row-to-column-in-t-sql)

Comment: What's the logic behind the gaps? When a new RevObjId is found the row number should be rounded up to odd if it is even? And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I have updated my question.

Comment: @RadimBača: No It is correct, I need the rownumber to change to the next odd number if the RevObjId changes. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. One possible solution is recursive SQL. Do you expect a set based solution? (probably with higher performance)

Comment: Now you've edited the query it will no longer return the stated results

Comment: @MartinSmith: I have edited and updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The need for this is highly suspect but I think this should do it.

The only time you get a gap is when the previous partition has an odd number of rows  - and then the gap is 1 row. So this keeps track of the running count of previous partitions with odd numbers of rows and adds 1 to the row number total for each such partition.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT RevObjId,
                LegalPartyId,
                IsPrimary,
                odd_adj = CASE
                            WHEN RevObjId = LEAD(RevObjId) 
                                    OVER (ORDER BY RevObjId ASC, IsPrimary DESC, LegalPartyId ASC)
                              THEN 0
                            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() /*We are in the last row of the partition so can use rownumber as a more efficient alternative to count*/
                                    OVER (PARTITION BY RevObjId ORDER BY IsPrimary DESC, LegalPartyId ASC)%2
                          END,
                RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() 
                                OVER(ORDER BY RevObjId ASC, IsPrimary DESC, LegalPartyId ASC)
         FROM   test)
SELECT RevObjId,
       LegalPartyId,
       IsPrimary,
       RowNumber
           +  SUM(odd_adj) OVER (ORDER BY RevObjId 
                                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
           - odd_adj AS RowNumber /*odd_adj is only potentially non zero for the last row in each partition 
                                   - if we are in the last row and it is 1 we need to deduct it 
                                     as this is not a previous partition */
FROM   T;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01d5c/34/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try it as follows

```
with groupcount as
(
  select RevObjId, (count(*) + 1)/ 2 * 2 as c
  from test
  group by RevObjId
), RevObjIdRN as
(
  select RevObjId, LegalPartyId, IsPrimary, 
         row_number() over (partition by RevObjId order by IsPrimary desc,LegalPartyId asc) as rn
  from test
)
select t2.RevObjId, t2.LegalPartyId, t2.IsPrimary, rn + relative
from (
  select RevObjId, sum(c) over (order by RevObjId) - c as relative
  from groupcount 
) t1  
join RevObjIdRN t2 on t1.RevObjId =  t2.RevObjId
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01d5c/32)

The solution is based on the following part:

```
with groupcount as
(
  select RevObjId, (count(*) + 1)/ 2 * 2 c
  from test
  group by RevObjId
)
select RevObjId, sum(c) over (order by RevObjId) - c as relative
from groupcount
```

which returns the starting `row_number` for each group of `RevObjId` (the `RevObjId` offset). The rest is simply adding `row_number()` for each `RevObjId` to this offset.